# delete object from array objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

I´m working with vuejs 3 and laravel.

I have this object array:

```
[[Target]]
: Array(3)
0: Proxy(Object) {id: '96', name: 'DESINCRUSTADOR DCALUXE - HIDROCAL ELECTRONICO', category: 'ARTICULOS B'}
1: Proxy(Object) {id: '56', name: 'ECONOMIZADOR DE AGUA ROSCA HEMBRA', category: 'ARTICULOS SECUNDARIOS'}
2: Proxy(Object) {id: '291', name: 'COLECCIÓN COCINA INTERNACIONAL, ALTA GASTRONOMÍA I…UILIBRADA Y SALUDABLE. HD - 3D, 2 TOMOS+1DVD (GD)', category: 'OBRAS LITERARIAS PEQUEÑAS'}
length: 3
```

and i have a function to delete element from my table:

```
const removeItem = (event) => {
        event.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
```

This delete my row ok, but i want update content of my array, that it´s a `ref([])`

```
const addItemCart = ref([])
```

To do this function i´m trying with this code:

```
let allRow = event.target.parentElement.parentElement;
        let firstTd = allRow.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].textContent

        addItemCart.value.forEach(element => {
            if(element.id == firstTd){
                for (const property in addItemCart.value) {
                    addItemCart.value = addItemCart.value.filter(item => addItemCart.value.id != firstTd);
                }
            }
        });

        console.log(addItemCart.value)
```

first i´m getting my tr and after i´m getting my first td that contain `ID` and after i´m trying to find coincidences in my array by id, if exist this id i want to remove it. Because if i select other item, in other function i´m using a `push` function and always i´m getting my olds items and new items.

How i can to do for delete this items from my array¿?

update:

```
const removeItem = (event) => {
        event.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove()

        let allRow = event.target.parentElement.parentElement;
        let firstTd = allRow.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].textContent

        addItemCart.value.forEach(element => {
            if(element.id == firstTd){
                if(element.id == firstTd){
                    for (const property in addItemCart.value) {
                        if(property.includes(firstTd)){
                            console.log("está");
                        }else{
                            console.log("no rula")
                        }
                        //addItemCart.value = addItemCart.value.filter(item => addItemCart.value.id != firstTd);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        console.log(addItemCart.value)
```

Thanks for readme and sorry for my bad english

Comment: You could check [Array includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to replace the first if check. If array doesn't include -> array filter

Comment: @PavlinPetkov thanks for your response, but i can´t solve my problem with ```includes``` update my question, with my actual code

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my question with this clean solution:

firt i´getting where are clicking in my table and get his parent and i´m getting index from my array that i´m setting in `td` `attr id`

i change my `v-for` to do this:

```
<tr v-for="(item, index) in addItemCart" :key="item.id">
                                    <td :id="index">{{ item.id }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ item.category }}</td>
                                    <td><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true" @click="removeItem($event)"></i></td>
                                </tr>
```

in my function `removeItem()`

```
const removeItem = (event) => {
        event.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove()

        let allRow = event.target.parentElement.parentElement;
        let firstTd = allRow.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].id;

        var index = addItemCart.value.indexOf(firstTd);
        addItemCart.value.splice(index, 1);
    }
```

And now i´m deleting row and item from array.